# User Grant in cassandra DB

Tags: cassandra

I would like a user `abc` to access only a single keyspace and no other keyspaces in the Database.
How can I achieve so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as described in [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlGrant.html):

```
GRANT <permission> ON <keyspace> TO <user>;
```

You need to setup authentication/authorization before, and [create user/role](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateRole.html).

Comment: I have done this. But the user is able to access all the keyspaces. How can I avoid this?

Comment: How did you create the user? what `LIST ALL PERMISSIONS OF <user>;` shows?  Have you tried to explicitly revoke permissions: http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/security.html#revoke-permission ?